# I'm trying to make a script that will make a part fade out. Please tell me what's wrong here?

Tags: lua, roblox

```
local TweenService = game:GetService("TweenService")
local part = workspace["road"]
local information = TweenInfo.new(1)
local Target = {transparency == 1}
local Tween = TweenService:create (part, information, Target)
wait(5)
Tween:play()
```

I'm getting the error "Unable to cast to Dictionary". How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
local Target = {["Transparency"] = 1}
```

Comment: Rather than just providing the solution, take the time and explain what is wrong too